# How to get Facebook share behavior with Facebook Connect on iPhone

Tags: iphone, facebook, facebook-sharer

With the standard share at `http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php` one only needs to specify a URL.  Title and thumbnail are automatically pulled from the web page (perhaps with the help of meta tags).

With Facebook Connect (I am using the iPhone SDK), I need to supply everything explicitly (URL, title, caption, description, images, etc.).

Is there a way to emulate the "share" behavior with Facebook Connect, i.e. let Facebook pull the missing elements from the page being shared itself?